# How to merge XML objects with jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, merge

I want to merge data of different XML files into one big XML tree. My idea is to append all upcoming nodes to the root node of the first XML file. However, I get a "TypeError" when trying to call "mergedXml.documentElement.appendChild". This is my code:

```
var mergedXml = undefined;

$.each(files, function(index, value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: value,
    cache: true,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(data);

      if (typeof mergedXml === 'undefined') {
        mergedXml = xmlDocument;
      } else {
        // New children
        var childNodes = xmlDocument.documentElement.childNodes;
        var children = childNodes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
          var node = childNodes[i];
          // How to append these nodes to the mergedXml root?
          // I tried:
          // mergedXml.documentElement.appendChild(node);
          // But then I get...
          // TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object. 
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error you're getting is caused by the fact that [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) removes the node from the original parent, so you're trying to access nodes which don't exist anymore. I would suggest replacing the `for` loop with a `while` loop:

```
var node;
while (xmlDocument.documentElement.hasChildNodes()) {
    node = xmlDocument.documentElement.childNodes[0];
    mergedXml.documentElement.appendChild(node); 
}
```

Full solution:

```
  var mergedXml = undefined;
  $.each(files, function(index, value) {
    $.ajax({
      url: value,
      cache: true,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) {
        var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(data);

        if (typeof mergedXml === 'undefined') {
          // Init XML collection
          mergedXml = xmlDocument;
        } else {
          // Add new children to XML collection
          var node;
          while (xmlDocument.documentElement.hasChildNodes()) {
            node = xmlDocument.documentElement.childNodes[0];
            mergedXml.documentElement.appendChild(node);
          }
        }

        if (index === files.length - 1) {
          console.log('Total nodes in root: ' + mergedXml.documentElement.childNodes.length);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```